# React stop/start fade-out on mouseEnter and mouseLeave without Jquery

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to show an error message as a toast(React Component) that will fade-out after certain seconds. However When the user hover-in the mouse on the toast while fading, the fade-out should stop and the toast should be restored to its initial state and when he hovers-out the mouse on the toast, the fade-out should start again. It can be achieved by using JQuery like this -

//function to start the fade-out after time - t sec

```
static  fadeOutToast(id, t) {
        let toast = document.getElementById(id);
        if (toast) {
          setTimeout(() => {
                   FadeAndRemove('#' + id);
          }, t * 1000);
         }
      }
```

/**
* t1 - time for fadeout animation
*/

```
 static FadeAndRemove(id,t1) {
        jQuery(id).fadeOut(t1 * 1000, function () {
          jQuery(this).hide();
        });
          handleReAppear(id);
      }


static handleReAppear(id) {
    jQuery(id).on("mouseover", function (e) {
      jQuery(this).stop(true).fadeIn(0);
    });

    jQuery(id).on("mouseleave", function (e) {
     FadeAndRemove(this);
    });
  }
```

Its working perfectly fine. However due to projects constraints I am not supposed to mixup Jquery and react.

I tried to achieve it by manipulating the CSS opacity on mouseEnter and mouseLeave events. The problem I face is the toast never goes away from the page using opacity. Is there any way in which we can detect when the opacity of the toast becomes 0 so that I can remove it from the page just when the opacity becomes 0 ?

Can someone help me in achieving the same without using Jquery ?

Comment: "I tried to achieve this using CSS by manipulating the opacity and visibility on mouseEnter and MouseLeave events on the toast respectively." What was the problem here? It's not clear what your problem is.

Comment: The problem that I am facing is we cannot remove the toast from the page  using opacity to 0 and so its still responsive on mouse hover event even after its opacity becomes 0 and if we remove the toast from the page using {display:none} or {visibility: hidden} we need to make sure that its only done when its opacity becomes 0(i.e after fading-out). Because before that the user may hover over it to stop the fading effect. Am I able to clear the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the fading animation I would use [React-Spring](http://react-spring.surge.sh/). With a `Spring` you can delay the start animation so it will fade-out after the delay.
Then you can add `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` event handler to detect the hovering of the toastr.

With this mouse detection you can toggle the `to` value of the Spring to `opacity` 1. That way it won't fade-out if the mouse is over the toast.

For the removal of the toastr you can use `onRest` of Spring and check if `opacity` is zero. `onRest` will be called as soon as the animation will end.

The state management is done inside `Toastr`component which will render all displayed `toasts`. This component will also handle the removal of the toast with no opacity.

For click event `addToast` I'm using a higher order component `withToastr` so I can add the prop of to the containing component.

For event handling I'm using [Eventemitter3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eventemitter3). If you're using Redux you could also use it to trigger the toasts.

In the next sections I'll give some details to every component that I've created in the following [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/z6k8xnlz3p). (Note: The snippets here are not running - for testing the code please have a look at the sandbox)

## `ToastrItem` component

Responsible for rendering a toast and for the animation.

```js
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { Spring } from "react-spring";
import styled from "styled-components";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class ToastrItem extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.string,
    timeout: PropTypes.number,
    destroy: PropTypes.func
  };
  static defaultProps = {
    timeout: 5000
  };

  state = {
    hovered: false
  };

  handleRest = ({ opacity }) => {
    if (opacity === 0) {
      this.props.destroy(this.props.id);
    }
  };

  handleMouseEnter = () => {
    this.setState({
      hovered: true
    });
  };

  handleMouseLeave = () => {
    this.setState({
      hovered: false
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { message, index, timeout } = this.props;
    const { hovered } = this.state;
    return (
      <Spring
        config={{ duration: 600, delay: timeout }}
        from={{ opacity: 1.0 }}
        to={{ opacity: hovered ? 1.0 : 0 }}
        onRest={this.handleRest}
      >
        {interpolated => (
          <Wrapper>
            <ToastBox
              onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}
              onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}
              pos={index}
              opacity={interpolated.opacity}
            >
              {message}
              {/*- debug info: {JSON.stringify(interpolated)}*/}
            </ToastBox>
          </Wrapper>
        )}
      </Spring>
    );
  }
}

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 100;
`;

const ToastBox = styled.div.attrs(props => ({
  style: {
    transform: `translateY(${props.pos * 80}px)`,
    opacity: props.opacity
  }
}))`
  width: 60%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  pointer-events: auto;
`;

export default ToastrItem;
```

The Spring is doing the animation as mentioned before. The mouse events `enter`/`leave` are setting local state `hovered` so we can change the animation end opacity - this will avoid the animation.
I've also tried `reset` prop from `React-Spring` but that wasn't working as expected.

## `Toastr` component

This component is managing the active toasts. Nothing special here. It's rendering the toasts array that are added with `addToast`.
`addToast` is creating a relatively unique key with timestamp and array index. It's needed so React is getting a key prop on the component. We could also use a uuid library here but I think the timestamp-id is OK.
`destroy` will be called if opacity is 0 then it's filter by key and update the state. The map is just there so we're updating the positions of the toasts.

```js
class Toastr extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    toasts: []
  };
  addToast = (message, config) => {
    const index = this.state.toasts.length;
    const id = `toastr-${Date.now()}-${index}`;
    const ToastComponent = (
      <ToastrItem
        key={id}
        id={id}
        index={index}
        message={message}
        timeout={config.timeout || 3000}
        destroy={this.destroy}
      />
    );
    this.setState(state => ({
      toasts: [...state.toasts, ToastComponent]
    }));
  };
  destroy = id => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      toasts: [
        ...state.toasts
          .filter(toast => toast.key !== id)
          .map((toast, index) => ({
            // map for updating index
            ...toast,
            props: {
              ...toast.props,
              index: index
            }
          }))
      ]
    }));
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    emitter.on("add/toastr", this.addToast);
  }
  render() {
    const { toasts } = this.state;
    return toasts;
  }
}

export const withToastr = WrappedComponent => {
  return class extends PureComponent {
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent addToast={actions.add} />;
    }
  };
};
```

## Usage in the app

We're adding `addToast` by using `withToastr(App)`. This will add the prop addToastr to the App component.
Then we're rendering the `Toastr` component that will manage & render our toasts.
Finally we add a button so we can trigger the toasts.

```js
class App extends Component {
  toastr;
  render() {
    const { addToast } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Toastr />
        <button onClick={() => addToast("Hello", { timeout: 4000 })}>
          Show toast
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const AppWithToasts = withToastr(App);
ReactDOM.render(<AppWithToasts />, rootElement);
```

## Conclusion

The code is working but I would add `native` prop to the Spring and I would also check if a transition would be a better fit for the use-case. See the example from [MessageHub example](https://codesandbox.io/s/rw1ymrlpvq?from-embed) from React-spring docs. Should be also possible to prevent the fade-out but I haven't checked.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to think about using the Animatable library.  It uses a declarative syntax that's quite easy to incorporate.

```
import * from 'react-native-animatable';

return(
        <Animatable.View animation="fadeOut" duration={2000} delay={1000}>
            <View>
               {/* YOUR CONTENT */}
            </View>
        </Animatable.View>
    );
```

https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable